# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substr' of undefined...works fine in IE but not chrome or FF

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Here's the page:
http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/mfr/rec/

It's been working fine in IE, Chrome, and FF for months, but now I get an error before the xml file is able to load...only in Chrome and FF...IE8 works fine.

Here's the error that FF: [13:51:18.454] TypeError: a is undefined @ http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/10/15a/main.js:25

And here's Chrome's error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substr' of undefined

I'm not sure how to isolate the error b/c it looks like it's part of the google api code.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?  Thanks for your time,

Shad

Answer (score 1):

v3.10 of the API is not compatible with markermanager v1.0; they released a [new version v1.1
that is compatible](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.1/).

See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4585) in the issue tracker.